# Having trouble when doing "mvn wildfly:deploy" using wildfly 10.1.0.Final, hibernate ogm 5.0.10.Final and Cassandra 3.0.9

Tags: maven, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, wildfly-10, hibernate-ogm

I have trouble doing "mvn wildfly:deploy".
Here is the error code:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project aigateway: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service."deployment.aigateway.war".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.aigateway.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.aigateway.war:main
> [ERROR] Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.hibernate:ogm"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.module.service."deployment.aigateway.war".main"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}}}
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sensorhound</groupId>
<artifactId>aigateway</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>AI Gateway Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty.version>9.3.12.v20160915</jetty.version>
    <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
    <ogm.version>5.0.10.Final</ogm.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.10.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- hibernate ogm -->
    <!-- Hibernate OGM Infinispan module; pulls in the OGM core module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-infinispan</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- standard APIs dependencies - provided in a Java EE container -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add the Narayana Transactions Manager
     an implementation would be provided in a Java EE container,
     but this works nicely in Java SE as well -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId>
        <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-spi</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId> <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId> 
        <version>${jetty.version}</version> </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource.leveldbjni</groupId>
        <artifactId>leveldbjni-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>aigateway</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <configuration>
            <force>true</force>
            <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
            <username>${wildfly-user}</username>
            <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="JPAService">
    <!-- Use the Hibernate OGM provider: configuration will be transparent -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="JBossAS" />
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2.1.Final" />
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="cassandra_experimental"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="127.0.0.1:9042"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="dev"/>         
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Here is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.hibernate" slot="ogm" services="export" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.ogm.cassandra" slot="main" services="export" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

I have the required module for hibernate ogm in:
*$WILDFLY_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/*

So I think wildfly should be able to find it.But when I want to deploy my project, it gives me that kind of moduleNutFoundException, I don't know why. Somebody please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<module name="org.hibernate" slot="ogm" services="export" />
```

with:

```
<module name="org.hibernate.ogm" slot="5.0" services="export" />
```

Also, you need to use ORM 5.0 with OGM 5.0, ORM 5.2.x won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

For more information, check out:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274171

Comment: For future reference, I think it would be nicer if you accept the answers somebody gave you instead of creating a new one that links to the same answer in a different place. You can always add a comment underneath. Otherwise you are not giving points to people who helped you.